# Copying files from multiple folders in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to copy files to a new folder using a windows batch command, but something is not working. I wonder What  I am doing wrong.

This works:

```
xcopy E:\folder\*.wav E:\wav\
```

But because I have many foldernames and the foldernames, I want to do this for each folder using this command:

```
xcopy E:\*\*.wav E:\wav\
```

But now it says:

```
File not found - *.wav
0 File(s) copied
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line (no batch):

```
for /d %F in (e:\*) do @if /i "%F" neq "e:\wav" 2>nul xcopy "%F\*.wav" "e:\wav"
```

The above will only copy files from the root level folders. If you want all `.wav` files from the entire drive, then you need:

```
for /r "e:\" %F in (.) do @if /i "%F" neq "e:\wav\." 2>nul xcopy "%F\*.wav" "e:\wav"
```

Double up the percents if you put the command in a batch file.

Note that different files that share the same name from different folders will collide - only one will survive in your \wav folder.

Comment: Thanks! What does `2>nul` mean?

Comment: It hides error messages in case a folder does not contain .wav files

Answer (score 0):

I have done some searching and trying, and this was what I came up with.

```
for /D %%d in (E:\*) do (
    for %%f in (%%d\*.wav) do (
        xcopy %%f E:\wav\
    )
)
```

Comment: Good effort, but you don't want to copy the files already in `e:\wav`. Also, you don't need the 2nd FOR loop.